# Openpyxl turning columns in lists?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Need to do some coding for a school project, but I am having trouble with producing an usable list from a column of data using Openpyxl (in Python). Here's the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

HISPARC = load_workbook(filename = "APPLES.xlsx")

sheet = HISPARC.active

i = 32
while i < 80:
    a = [sheet.cell(row = i, column = 11)]
    i = i + 3

    print(a[0].value)
```

It prints everything. Also, if I were to place a independent piece of code before printing the only number that will print is the last cell in the column and nothing else.

What I want to do is to produce a list of the cells generated above so that I can use their values later on.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest looking up how to create and add to a list in python. If you are still stuck, please edit the question with specifically how.

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [c.value for c in ws['L'][32:80]]
```

Will give you the a list of all the values for the cells L31 to L:81 which it seems is what you want.